# How to stream a Mono<list<Object>> through Spring webflux?

Tags: json, spring, mono, streaming, spring-webflux

Spring webflux Json streaming is not working for a Flux object converted into Mono<list. It only receives a single response which results in AWS Timeout. Result service will call a reactive repository query it will return Flux and I want to convert it into a DAO object which is returning Mono<List<>>

```
  @GetMapping(value= "/resultMonoStream/{id}", produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
             public ResponseEntity<Mono<List<ResultDao>>> getAllResultMonoStream() {
                    Flux<Result> result = resultService.getAllResult(id);
                    Mono<List<ResultDao>> response = result.map(entity-> entity.convertToFlatObject()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition

- Mono is either 1 value or no value.
- Flux can contain from 0 up to N values.

> It only receives a single response

Because Mono is handled as a single element. So by definition mostly 1 element can be streamed.

Comment: My entire APIs are started streaming like all the endpoints are streaming data now but this happens only in the hosted application but it is not reproducible in local STS. The funniest part the Flux is getting an internal server error while trying to fetch 15000 records but normal api are fetching and streaming such huge amount of data